# Not in scope: data constructor?

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell. I am getting this problem :

Assignment12.hs:5:12: Not in scope: data constructor `Suit'

Assignment12.hs:5:18: Not in scope: data constructor `Rank'

Assignment12.hs:6:11: Not in scope: data constructor `Rank'

Assignment12.hs:7:11: Not in scope: data constructor `Rank'

Assignment12.hs:8:11: Not in scope: data constructor `Otherwise'
Failed, modules loaded: none.

This is my code :

```
data Suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades deriving (Show, Eq)
data Rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num Int deriving (Show, Eq)
type Card = (Suit, Rank)
cardValue :: Card -> Int
cardValue (Suit, Rank)
     | Rank == Ace = 11
     | Rank == Ace = 11
     | Rank == Jack = 10
     | Otherwise = Num
```

I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: You have `Ace` twice and aren't handling `King` or `Queen` - it looks like `Ace` should have value 13 then `King`, `Queen`, `Jack`?

Answer (score 22):

In haskell variable names must start with a lowercase letter. Anything that is uppercase is interpreted by the compiler as a [Data Constructor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor) which is why you are getting that error.

When you define `cardRank` the variables `(suit, rank)` must start with lowercase letters for your code to compile.

This should work

```
data Suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades deriving (Show, Eq)
data Rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num Int deriving (Show, Eq)
type Card = (Suit, Rank)

cardValue :: Card -> Int
cardValue (suit, rank)
     | rank == Ace = 11
     | rank == Ace = 11
     | rank == Jack = 10
cardValue (suit, Num x) = x
```

Comment: `Num` in the `otherwise` clause is not an `Int` so this won't compile.